# Order contour points in clockwise

Tags: image-processing, geometry, coordinate-transformation, plotting

I want to describe shape of an object using contour points descriptor. Given a silhouette (image black white of an object), I extrait the contour points using EdgeDetect[] fonction. After that, I need to order these points  as clockwise order starting from a given point p.

I try like this:
1) get the centroid.
2) Apply that as an offset to every point(subtract from the array)
3) For each point treat X and Y as real and imaginary and convert to Polar. bundle these as a  cluster with angle first
4) Sort the array that this creates.
5) For each point convert back to X and Y
6) Add the offset back on.
In this case some points does not respect the order.
here is my code:
![image used[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KAMsi.png)

```
    centroid = 
     ComponentMeasurements[silhouette, "Centroid"][[All, 2]] // Flatten
    contourImage = EdgeDetect[silhouette];

    contourData = ImageData[contourImage];


    coordContourData = PixelValuePositions[contourImage, 1];

    normalizedContourData = (coordContourData[[#]] - centroid) & /@ 
       Range[1, Length[coordContourData]];

    angles = Table[
      N[ArcTan[normalizedContourData[[i, 1]], 
        normalizedContourData[[i, 2]]/Degree]], {i, 1, 
       Length[normalizedContourData]}]
orderedcontourpoints = coordContourData[[Ordering[angles]]];

emptyImage = Image[Table[0, {i, 1, 600}, {j, 1, 800}]];

Manipulate[
 ReplacePixelValue[emptyImage, 
  orderedcontourpoints[[1 ;; i]] -> 1], {i, 1, Length[angles], 1}]
```

I need to rectify this problem and I need to start from a given point, for example the point in the left having the same y as the centroid. Any suggestions please?

Comment: I think that I have to add the norm r as a second sorted criteria.

Comment: I don't have time to look at your code but it sounds like you should use `FindShortestPath`: `positions = PixelValuePositions[EdgeDetect@img, 1]; 
Graphics[
 Line[
  positions[[
    Last@FindShortestTour[positions]
    ]]
  ]
 ]` (cycle the list until it starts with your point, reverse it if necessary)

Comment: If by "respect the order" you mean what I think you mean, then the whole method will only work if the region is star-shaped (in the mathematical sense of that term) with respect to the centroid.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau, thanks, I responsed the question

Comment: @DanielLichtblau, my response fail on some silhouettes.

Comment: Like I said, I expect it to fail when the region is not star-shaped with respect to the centroid.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau, I implement an algo that seems work fine. I want just to check if the positions returned by PixelValuePositions[] are the same returned by the tools coordinates when we "click right" on a an image on mathematica?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function can be used to generate the contour points in the clockwise order. The starting point is fixed as the left point having the same y as the centroid of the contour.

```
ContourBasedFeature[silhouette_] := 
 Module[{centroid, startpoint, positions, contourPoints, order, 
   clockwiseorder}, (
   centroid = 
    ComponentMeasurements[silhouette, "Centroid"][[All, 2]] // Flatten;
   positions = PixelValuePositions[EdgeDetect@silhouette, 1];
   startpoint = 
    Select[positions, #[[2]] == Ceiling[centroid[[2]]] && #[[1]] < 
        Ceiling[centroid[[1]]] &];
   contourPoints = 
    Join[startpoint, DeleteCases[positions, startpoint // Flatten]];
   order = contourPoints[[Last@FindShortestTour[contourPoints]]];
   If[order[[1, 2]] > order[[2, 2]],
    Join[{order[[1]]}, order[[Range[Length[order], 2, -1]]]],
    order
    ]
   )]
```

I call the function using the below silhouette noted sil22.

```
emptyImage = Image[Table[0, {i, 1, 300}, {j, 1, 400}]]
    clockwiseorder = ContourBasedFeature[sil22]
    Manipulate[
     ReplacePixelValue[emptyImage, clockwiseorder[[1 ;; i]] -> 1], {i, 1, 
      Length[clockwiseorder], 1}]
```

[image: sil22]